# Where could `appendTo()` be usable with an `htmlString`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

The API docs for [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) list the method being able to select an HTML string for a target.

However, there seems to be no use to this since the set still includes the original elements, and the HTML string seems not to have been added anywhere in the DOM nor do I see a circumstance where it could be available.

```
var b = button.appendTo('<div>').appendTo('body');
```

`b` is a button, and yet it is not wrapped in a `div` or anything.

You can see this at http://jsfiddle.net/0dgLe5sj/

Where would it be useful to append to a HTML string (which doesn't yet exist on the page)?

Comment: not sure exactly what you wanna do but if so did you notice you used a bracketed (tagged) div `<div>` and an untagged body `body`, aint it supposed to be `<body>`

Comment: I want to show what I thought was the uselessness of `<div>` in that even with appending to the body--which I meant to be a selector, as I know it would be completely useless if I didn't eventually add to the document--seems that `<div>` occurs nowhere and appeared to have no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appendTo()` returns the item being appended.

So your code is:

```
var btn = button.appendTo('<div>');
btn.appendTo('body');
```

As you can see, you move it inside a div, *then* immediately move it inside the body.  So you when you look at it at the end, it's inside the body.

Perhaps you meant:

```
var b = button.appendTo($('<div>').appendTo('body'));
```

which will append a `div` to the body and then append the btn to that div.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0dgLe5sj/8/

or, if you wanted to add to the div first:

```
var b = button.appendTo("<div>");
b.parent().appendTo("body")
```

but if you combine it into a single line, you can't get the button back into the variable using `.appendTo` as you're adding the `div` to the body so you're going to get the div or the body back.

---

To address the 'where would this be useful part':

Being able to create *detached* DOM elements is extremely useful for parsing HTML strings and can also be used to 'batch' up some changes without forcing page redraws between.

Moving one button to a detached div and the back to the body doesn't have a lot of point, but it proves the principles.

Comment: Ok, I see, the latter part of your answer answered my question--I see it does have some use to append to an HTML string. But what has confused me is that the usage in your latter example seems to have little benefit--I can't see where this style would be useful, whereas the first example has clear uses...

Comment: It's more about what you're trying to achieve.  If you want to move a button inside a new div on the page, just use the first code.  If you want to move a button inside a *detached* div first, for whatever reason, use the second code.   While your question *is* asking where this would be useful, it was also asking this in a manner based on an incorrect technical solution, so I've provided the fix for the technical solution.  ("b is a button, and yet it is not wrapped in a div" - now it is a wrapped in a div, so perhaps you can now answer your own question).

Comment: Re: your follow-up, yes, I get how detached elements can be useful, but the API here is just a little awkward because it doesn't automatically make the `parent()` call for you so you can actually do something with the newly created item. But for parity with the other argument types, I see why it is this way, because when you attach to say a selector instead, it is convenient for the chain to continue referencing the item appended.

Comment: That's what `append` is for.  `$("<div/>").append(button).appendTo("body");`

Comment: In other words, you don't think html strings are very useful with `appendTo` either... :-)